# Async Ajax call not working in chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, asynchronous, progress

I have a form within an aspx page,this form takes a file input and posts it to viddler server.

While the file gets posted to viddler server,In the backgorund i make ajax calls to a webmethod on the codebehind page, this webmethod calls the viddler server and returns the upload progress for that particular upload.

These Ajax calls are working fine in firefox, but not working in chrome,they are not even coming up in the chrome Network panel and none of these functions (success,error or complete) are firing.

Am i missing anything here?

Here is my ajax call:

```
    function checkProgress() {
        tokenValue = document.getElementById("uploadtoken").value;
        var y = "{ token: 'token' }";

        var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ token: tokenValue });

      $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: "video_viddlerUpload.aspx/CheckProgress",
             data: jsonText,
             contentType: 'application/json',
         dataType: 'json',
         cache: false,
         async: true,
         success: function(json) {

                var uploadProgress;
                uploadProgress = eval('(' + json.d + ')');


                   },
                 error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {


             alert('There was an error uploading your file. Please try  again.');
          },
                complete:function () {
                    alert('complete');
                  }
    }); 

    }
```

Please help me. I will be very helpful.

Comment: `var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ token: tokenValue });` not making sense..

Comment: it's same as var jsonText = "{"token":"u04d88"}";   that webmethod takes an input parameter called "token"

Comment: Are you ever calling your function `checkProgress()`? Also, I don't think you need to explicitly `stringify` your POST data.

Comment: Then there should probably be some error message in Chromes Console

Comment: Yes i am calling checkProgress(), and there are no errors in console. However on the network panel there is a pending post to viddler server,as the file is being uploaded. would this pending post stop ajax calls?

Answer (score 0):

Guess the problem is with `cache:false` as the [jQuery Doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) says - " Setting cache to `false` will only work correctly with `HEAD` and `GET` requests. It works by appending "`_={timestamp}`" to the `GET` parameters. The parameter is not needed for other types of requests, except in IE8 when a `POST` is made to a `URL` that has already been requested by a `GET`." and u are doing a `POST` request.